# How to delete session in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6

I am able to log in into application even after logging out, by clicking the back button on search bar.

For some strange reasons, I am not able to delete the session completely.

I am not using any gem. I want to create rails authentication from scratch.

Sessions Controller:

```
 class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
      log_in user
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    reset_session
    redirect_to root_path
  end

end
```

Application Helper

```
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  helper_method :current_user,:logged_in?, :logged_in_user,:current_user

   def log_in(user)
     session[:user_id] = user.id
   end

   def current_user
      @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
   end

   def logged_in?
     !current_user.nil?
   end

   def logged_in_user
     unless logged_in?
       flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
       redirect_to new_session_path
     end
   end


   def current_user?(user)
     user == current_user
    end

end
```

Allpication.html.erb

```
  <body>

    <div class="container">

       <% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
          <div class="alert alert-<%= message_type %>"><%= message %></div>
       <% end %>

       <header>

         <% if logged_in? %>
           <%= link_to "Log out", sessions_path, method: "delete" %>
           <%= link_to "Edit", edit_user_path(current_user) %>
         <% else %>
           <li>
             <%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_path %>
           </li>
           <li>
             <%= link_to "Log in", new_sessions_path %>
           </li>
         <% end %>



         </header>
         <%= yield %>
       </div>
    </body>
```

Please help me. I am going nuts.

User Controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:new, :show, :edit, :update]
    before_action :correct_user, only: [:new, :show, :edit, :update]

    def index
      @users = User.all
    end

    def new
      @user = User.new
    end

    def create
      @user = User.new(set_params)
      if @user.save
        redirect_to new_session_url
      else
        render 'new'
      end
    end

    def show
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      @posts = @user.posts
    end

    def edit
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
       @user = User.find(params[:id])
       if @user.update(update_params)
        redirect_to @user
      else
        render 'edit'
      end
    end



    private

    def set_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
    def update_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end


    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url)  unless current_user?(@user)
    end


end
```

User is able to log in only he/she logged in.

I have updated my code as per what i have been suggested or what i have i tried.

Comment: What happens if you change the user_id to something invalid like 0 or -1? does that change persists? What happens if you delete the key from the session hash inside the controller action instead of the helper method?

Comment: I tried what you said. Same thing happens.

Comment: The back button on a browser will load a cache by default. If you hit back then press refresh do you remain logged in?

Comment: Yes, same thing happens .

Comment: Also, the common way of doing this is to have a before_action in your application helper which is used by every page that requires login, checking if the user should be able to access that page. Do you have controls on each controller? Or does login only change the content of the page, rather than what’s accessible?

Comment: I am using before_Action in User's controller, not in the sessions controller.

Comment: things to check: 1. when the user logs out, does the session object _actually_ get deleted from the db? (user the rails console)  2. (if yes) when the user later visits a page, how is it happening that ```current_user``` is not nil? (use the debugger)

Comment: After user logouts.

Comment: After has logged out -> User's console .                                                                        
Started DELETE "/sessions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-11-04 22:16:46 +0530
Processing by SessionsController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"tEx9oXMuJUBranuCvP1yqrTjHGMGjBpaZNWWUe0E6HOhGD+FWfFmqj5zerXYvY56XhC1/60IaxZJEvBRMQFuaA=="}
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 418)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, this is happening because Rails is caching.

You can do the following to get around this issue.

In your `ApplicationController`, put the following code

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_action :set_cache_buster

  private
    def set_cache_buster
      response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
      response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
      response.headers["Expires"] = "Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT"
    end
end
```

Comment: Works Perfectly. Thank you so much.